# Duplicate and incorrect legends

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am creating a plot and have few issues:

1. Legends are duplicated
2. Legends are shown incorrectly on the left, instead of the right
3. Same value of legend is shown incorrect for different values and colors
4. Plots are overlapped

- I am plotting svIonoStdev vs ITow when sourceid= 0 and 1.
- With this I need to groupthem based on svGnssId and svSvId.
- I am able to group them, but the legends are not shown correctly.

**Below is code I tried:**

Since my DF is too big (around 60K rows) I converted the first 15 rows of my DF into dict and sharing here

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

new_msg_dict = {
    'sourceId': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0],
    'iTOW': [518490.0, 518490.0, 518490.0, 518490.0, 518490.0, 518490.0, 518490.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518492.0, 518493.0, 518493.0],
    'svGnssId': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], 
    'svSvId': [1.0, 10.0, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0, 27.0, 32.0, 1.0, 10.0, 14.0, 21.0, 22.0, 27.0, 32.0, 1.0, 10.0],
    'ionoCorr': [-0.14, 0.034, 1.973, -1.09, 7.136, 4.187, 2.006, -0.14, 0.034, 1.973, -1.09, 7.136, 4.187, 2.0060000000000002, -0.14, 0.034],
    'svIonoStdev': [0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.05, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03]
}
new_msg_df = pd.DataFrame(new_msg_dict)
satellite = 'GPS'

new_gk_stddev = list(new_msg_df.groupby(['svGnssId', 'svSvId', 'sourceId', 'svIonoStdev']))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, constrained_layout=True)
for i in new_gk_stddev:
    if i[0][2] == 1.0:
        ax[0].plot(i[1]['iTOW'], i[1]['svIonoStdev'], label=f"{satellite} {i[0][1]}")
        ax[0].set_ylabel("Standard deviation (TECU)")
        ax[0].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
        ax[0].grid(True)
        ax[0].legend(fontsize=4)
        ax[0].set_title('Correction Handler Output')
    elif i[0][2] == 2.0:
        ax[1].plot(i[1]['iTOW'], i[1]['svIonoStdev'], label=f"{satellite} {i[0][1]}")
        ax[1].set_ylabel("Standard deviation (TECU)")
        ax[1].set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
        ax[1].grid(True)
        ax[1].legend(fontsize=4)
        ax[1].set_ylim([0, 0.05])
        ax[1].set_title('HPG Filter Output')
```

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

This is part of my DF:

[image]

Comment: Hi , I updated . hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

An important problem with the code is the name `i` in:

```
new_gk_stddev = list(new_msg_df.groupby(['svGnssId', 'svSvId', 'sourceId', 'svIonoStdev']))
for i in new_gk_stddev:
    ...
```

This makes the code extremely hard to read, follow, debug and improve. `i` should be replaced by variable names that tell what's going on.  The first part of `i` are the keys from the call to `groupby`. Therefore, logical variable names would just be `svGnssId, svSvId, sourceId, svIonoStdev`.  The last part in `i` are the rows of the dataframe that go with one instance of these 4 variables.  We could call this `line_df`, as will be used as input to draw one horizontal line. Converting the 4 columns that are floats that represent integers to just integers, makes the numbers easier to read and to reason about.

We can also leave out the conversion to `list`, as this just takes up time and memory. Further, all the changes to the labels etc. for `ax[0]` and `ax[1]` only need to happen once.  Putting these outside the `for` loop would make the code both clearer and more efficient.

The loop itself would then look like:

```py
new_gk_stddev = new_msg_df.groupby(['svGnssId', 'svSvId', 'sourceId', 'svIonoStdev'])
for (svGnssId, svSvId, sourceId, svIonoStdev), line_df in new_gk_stddev:
    if sourceId == 1:
        ax[0].plot(line_df['iTOW'], line_df['svIonoStdev'], label=f"{satellite} {svSvId}")
    elif sourceId == 2:
        ax[1].plot(line_df['iTOW'], line_df['svIonoStdev'], label=f"{satellite} {svSvId}")
```

As `sourceId` just chooses between `ax[0]` and `ax[1]`, this choice can be stored into a dictionary `ax_from_sourceId = {1: ax[0], 2: ax[1]}`, reducing the code further to:

```
for (svGnssId, svSvId, sourceId, svIonoStdev), line_df in new_gk_stddev:
    ax_from_sourceId[sourceId].plot(line_df['iTOW'], line_df['svIonoStdev'], label=f"{satellite} {svSvId}")
```

Here we see that with `svIonoStdev` being constant in this call, a horizontal line is drawn between all the corresponding `iTOW` values. (If there would be only one `iTOW` value, nothing is shown. If multiple lines would be drawn onto the same spots, only the last one drawn will be visible, hiding the ones below.)

The label is assigned depending on `svSvId`, so probably you want the color to depend on that `svSvId`.  These colors should be assigned in the code, as matplotlib's automatic assignment doesn't know about the needed correspondence.  We could collect all unique values in a list `svSvId_list = new_msg_df['svSvId'].unique` and create a dictionary mapping each of them to a specific color.

Matplotlib creates its standard legends by looking at all the elements in the plot that have a label assigned.  If a label is assigned in each step of the `for` loop, there will be a lot of repetition.  The easiest is to create a custom legend from the list of `svSvId` and their colors.

By default, the legend is placed at what matplotlib calls the "best" position (chosen between the 4 corners, the 4 centers of the borders and the plot center).  If all these places are too full, the legend is just placed in the upper left corner. With `ax.legend(..., loc='upper right')` it would be placed at the upper right. Another option is to place the legend just outside the plot, where `bbox_to_anchor=...` sets a position, and `loc=` tells which corner of the legend is "anchored" to that position. As the legend is the same for both subplots, we can leave out one of them.

Personally, I don't understand what exactly is going on with `plt.subplots(..., constraint_layout=True)`.  I prefer to call `plt.tight_layout()` and the end of the code to make labels and legend nicely fit into the plot.

Here is how the modified code could look like:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
import pandas as pd

# get the data from disk (or from a dictionary)
new_msg_df = pd.DataFrame(new_msg_dict)

# convert these columns to integer type
new_msg_df['sourceId'] = new_msg_df['sourceId'].astype(int)
new_msg_df['iTOW'] = new_msg_df['iTOW'].astype(int)
new_msg_df['svGnssId'] = new_msg_df['svGnssId'].astype(int)
new_msg_df['svSvId'] = new_msg_df['svSvId'].astype(int)

satellite = 'GPS'

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
ax_from_sourceId = {1: ax[0], 2: ax[1]}
svSvId_list = sorted(new_msg_df['svSvId'].unique())  # make a list of the possible svSvId values
cmap = plt.get_cmap('turbo', len(svSvId_list))  # a colormap with a color for each svSvId
color_dict = {svSvId: cmap(i) for i, svSvId in enumerate(svSvId_list)}

new_gk_stddev = new_msg_df.groupby(['svGnssId', 'svSvId', 'sourceId', 'svIonoStdev'])
for (svGnssId, svSvId, sourceId, svIonoStdev), line_df in new_gk_stddev:
    ax_from_sourceId[sourceId].plot(line_df['iTOW'], line_df['svIonoStdev'], color=color_dict[svSvId])

legend_handles = [Line2D([], [], lw=2, color=color_dict[svSvId], label=f"{satellite} {svSvId}")
                  for svSvId in svSvId_list]
for ax_i in ax:
    ax_i.set_ylabel("Standard deviation (TECU)")
    ax_i.set_xlabel("Itows (mSec)")
    ax_i.grid(True)
    # ax_i.legend(handles=legend_handles, fontsize=4, loc='upper right') # legend inside plot

ax[0].set_title('Correction Handler Output')
ax[1].set_title('HPG Filter Output')
# legend outside plot, only for ax[0]:
ax[0].legend(handles=legend_handles, fontsize=4, loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=[1.01, 1.02])

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```